# How to convert this sequence of sums using $\sum$ notation?

Tags: summation, notation

If I had this sequence

$x-2x+3x-4x+....+(2n-1)x-2nx$

And I want to rewrite this using the $\sum$ notation.

I know I can just guess what the formula could be, but is there some technique to it that I can use to guarantee that I get the formula on the first try?

Sorry in advance if this seems like a dumb question.

Comment: Not really, unfortunately.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that what you're looking at is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k+1} kx
$$
?

Comment: Why write it as a sum. Can't you just use the result: $-nx$ ?

Comment: The body of your question asks for techniques to calculate the sum, which is not what your title is saying. Which is it? Do you want to convert the sum into a $\sigma$ notation, or do you want to calculate the sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line the terms up next to an index. One way is like so:
$$
\begin{array}{*7{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & 2n-1 & 2n \\
x & -2x & 3x & -4x & \dots & (2n-1)x & -2nx
\end{array}
$$
Ignoring the $\pm$ signs for a moment, notice that each term has a coefficient that matches the index. Also, notice that each term has a factor of $x$. Let's let $k$ denote the index (so $1 \leq k \leq 2n$). Then, we have $\pm kx$ in the $k$th term.

How to get the signs to alternate? The standard way is to use successive powers of $-1$, i.e. $(-1)^k$. This does alternate, but it's parity is wrong: even terms are positive while odd terms are negative. To fix this, notice that
$$
-(-1)^k = (-1)^1 (-1)^k = (-1)^{k+1} 
$$
works. It would also work to use $(-1)^{k-1}$, or even $(-1)^{k+j}$ for any odd number $j$.

Putting this all together, our $k$th term looks like $(-1)^{k+1}kx$, and so the sum is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k+1}kx.
$$

Comment: Yes. Nice catch! I edited.